# Telegram, Python-telegram-bot==13.13, webhook

Tags: python, django, webhooks, python-telegram-bot

help me figure out what the error is. I redesigned the bot to work from a webhook I will receive a reply from a telegram POST /webhook/ 200 OK but the bot stopped responding to commands when I press /start the bot is silent. Tell me where I went wrong? thanks in advance

I start everything on django for port 8050

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from decouple import config
import json


TOKEN = config('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)
dp = updater.dispatcher


@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    print('this is webhook')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        update = Update.de_json(json.loads(request.body), bot)
        dp.process_update(update)

    return HttpResponse('ok')


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    print('this is start')
    update.message.reply_text('Hello World!')


def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    print('this is echo')
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('this is main')

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))
    updater.start_webhook(
        listen="0.0.0.0",
        port=8050,
    )

    updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

if **name** == '**main**':
print('this is main')

```
updater.start_webhook(
    listen="0.0.0.0",
    port=8443,
)

updater.idle()
```

I just moved the commands from main above and everything worked

Comment: Make sure to put all code into a code block. It seems that some code isn't formatted properly making this post hard to read. (I would edit this myself, but the edit queue is full atm) Thanks!